# Genexus prompt input parameters

Tags: parameters, prompt, genexus

I have a Web Panel with this Param Rule:

```
parm(out:&pLocalidadId, in:&pProvinciaId);
```

and in a Work With Web form I want to use this Web Panel, using the Prompt Rule (in the Web Panel generated):

```
&ProvinciaId = ProvinciaId;
prompt(Gx0180, LocalidadId, &ProvinciaId);
```

but it allwais pass 0 for the input &pProvinciaId parameter.

Comment: Attribute LocalidadId must be enabled and visible in the Form.

Comment: I've removed the prompt rule in the Transaction and added in the Work With generated Web Panel and worked the prompt, but it doesn't pass the ProvinciaId parameters, it gives me allways 0

Answer (score 0):

Is Attribute LocalidadId visible and enabled within the Form?

The documentation says:

> If the Prompt references several out parameters, at least one of them must be enabled in the Form; otherwise the Prompt rule will not be enabled.

[Prompt Rule](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Prompt%20rule)

Comment: I've removed the prompt rule in the Transaction and added in the Work With generated Web Panel and worked the prompt, but it doesn't pass the ProvinciaId parameters, it gives me allways 0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the rule that sets &ProvinciaId doesn't execute before the prompt rule.

You could try to change the prompt rule to send the attribute as the parameter:
`prompt(Gx0180, LocalidadId, ProvinciaId);`

or put `&ProvinciaId = ProvinciaId;` in ProvinciaId.IsValid event.

Comment: Hi Guille. The first try was with the prompt(Gx0180, LocalidadId, ProvinciaId);but it didn't worked. In some forum it says that genexus doesn't know to witch property to asign the prompt so I changed one to a variable